# how do you run arguments in a custom monitor on uptime

Tags: windows, batch-file, uptime

i am trying to run a custom monitor in the up-time monitoring system and when i have it open a .bat that i have created it gives me an error stating that the @echo off is not a command.

the .bat file contains

```
@echo off
start c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe
```

when i run the .bat in windows it opens up openssl and lets me pass in information

the error i am getting when running on uptime is

> Status: OK Message:
>
> D:\uptime software\scripts\custom>ï»¿@echo off
>
> D:\uptime software\scripts\custom>start
>   c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe  , error data returned: 'ï»¿@echo' is
>   not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file. Output:
>
> D:\uptime software\scripts\custom>ï»¿@echo off
>
> D:\uptime software\scripts\custom>start
>   c:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe  Response time: 531 ms

I need the custom monitor to open the .bat and have it pass in commands to check the xml web sites through their corresponding ports.

for example i need this web site for XML to be checked "blank-xml.mycompany.com:4021"

i can run `s_client -connect blank-xml.mycompany.com:4021` in openssl and see that the port is actually active and running. then i check the packages that have been loaded by running `<BL30DOC><XPLN/></BL30DOC>` and it returns information of the current packages that have been loaded.

how would i get the .bat to open with up-time and pass in arguments that are needed to run?

**Update**

I have changed the encoding to the .bat to be ANSI and now get this response from uptime

> Status: OK Message: (No output) Output: Response time: 547 ms

the problem now seems to be that the argument i want to run is actually not doing anything.

the argument i am trying to run is s_client -connect blank-xml.mycompany.com:4021 and i still get the same response from up-time with the argument in place.

Comment: It looks like you used a text editor that saved the batch file with some Unicode BOM (judging by the `ï»¿` characters before the `@echo off` command). Don't do that - save it as plain text without a BOM.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: i figured out that i needed to save the .bat with the encoding as ANSI

Comment: Depends on the editor.  If you're using Notepad++ I think the Encoding menu --> Convert to ANSI would do it.